# Jquery. What is the difference between these functions $(document).ready and $(window).load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between these functions `$(document).ready` and `$(window).load`, for example if i am want one use for run code when all page is complete load? As these functions are implemented in pure JavaScript? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.onload = function() {

    alert( "welcome" );

};
```

Unfortunately, the code doesn't run until all images are finished downloading, including banner ads. To run code as soon as the document is ready to be manipulated, jQuery has a statement known as the ready event:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    // Your code here.

});
```

*Source from http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/*

Plus, `$(document).ready(function(){});` It call function by call back. You can define many `$(document).ready` . It 'll run all .

`window.onload = function(){}` . 
 "assign" => When you define many `window.onload = ...`, It just run last function.

Comment: `$(window).load()` and `window.onload = ...` is not the same thing, but do the same thing. You can have has much `$(window).load()` event you want but it is not recommanded (same with the DOM ready method). It is the same as `window.addEventListener('load', function(){})`. Also, it is not *unfortunate* that the code run only when *"all images are finished"*.

Answer (score 1):

`$(document).ready()` fires as soon as the DOM is ready and you can mess with the DOM elements.
`$(window).load()` fires when loading of the page content (including images) is done.

Answer (score 1):

`document.ready` will execute right after the HTML document is loaded property, and the DOM is ready.

`document.ready` (a jQuery event) will fire when all the elements are in place, and they can be referenced in the JS code, but the content is not necessarily loaded.

the `window.load` however will wait for the page to be fully loaded, this includes inner frames, images etc.

`window.load` is a built-in JavaScript method, it is known to have some quirks in old browsers (IE6, IE8, old FF and Opera versions) but will generally work in all of them.

`window.load` can be used in the body's onload event like this (but I would strongly suggest you avoid mixing code like this in the HTML, as it is a source for confusion later on):